# VB.NET how to convert Object(,) to String()

Tags: arrays, vb.net, object, type-conversion, epplus

i am currently ready data from excel per EPPlus interface. My Excel is a csv file.

I've already the data available in a **object(,)** property (for me a unknown format).

Which format is that? How can i convert it to a String Array?

Comment: It looks like a 2 dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean like this...

```
Private Class TestIt
    Dim strvar1 As String = Nothing
    Dim strvar2 As String = Nothing
    Dim Split As Object = MyFunc("A")

    strvar1 = Split(0)
    strvar2 = Split(1)
End Class

'Extra class or something
Public Function MyFunc(Test As String) As Object
    Dim var1 As String = Nothing
    Dim var2 As String = Nothing
    Select Case (Test)
        Case "A"
            var1 = "one"
            var2 = "two"
        Case "B"
            var = "three"
            var2 = "four"
    End Select
    Return {var1, var2}
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't realized that it was a two-dimensional array.

The Problem was to find out the maximum number of each dimension.

I've found the following functions:

Array.getUpperBound(dimension)

So that solves my problem.

But many thanks for your fast answer!!